# Bootstrap 4 card-deck with wrapper element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm working with Angular (v4.3.1) and Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6). A template contains two subcomponents like so:

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <comp1></comp1>
    <comp2></comp2>
</div>
```

Both subcomponent's templates have as root element's class the `.card` Bootstrap class.

```
<div class="card">
    ...
</div>
```

This, once compiled results in the following HTML

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <comp1 _nghost-c3="">
        <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="card">
            ...
        </div>
    </comp1>
    <comp2 _nghost-c4="">
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="card">
            ...
        </div>
    </comp2>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `.card-deck` styling doesn't get applyed properly if there is an element wrapping the `.card` elements.

A Bootstrap only example, the problem is strictly related to Bootstrap css and not Angular obviously.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  Displayed properly  -->
  <div id="deck-without-wrapper" class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p>Card1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p>Card2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!--  NOT displayed properly  -->
  <div id="deck-with-wrapper" class="card-deck">
    <div id="wrapper1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>Card1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>Card2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyone knows a way to get both the components structure and the styling working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wrappers are causing trouble because a div doesn't have any flex css properties,  While the `.card` classes are using `flex:1 0 0;`

Option 1 (preferred): **Apply the `.card` class to the angular host element wrapper, instead of the first child element**.
I've not used angular, going by [these docs](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-advanced-styling-guide-v4-f0765616e635) you could set a class on the host element. Using `@Component.host`.

Or define some rules using [angulars custom renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639708/1203738).
I can't advice you on the best approach, I lack the knowledge on angular.

In the end you would want to end up with `<comp1 _nghost-c3="" class="card">`

Option 2 (not very sane): **Pretend that the wrappers are cards**,
and style them like a card would be styled.
*I would advice against this*.
 It can cause troubles in the long run. IE newer bootstrap versions could change the css styling, and you might forget to update these custom rules.

```css
.card-deck > div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  flex-direction:column;
  
}

.card-deck > div:not(:last-child){
 margin-right:15px;
 }
 

.card-deck > div:not(:first-child)
{
margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--  Displayed properly  -->
  <div id="deck-without-wrapper" class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p>Card1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <p>Card2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!--  NOT displayed properly  -->
  <div id="deck-with-wrapper" class="card-deck">
    <div id="wrapper1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>Card1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>Card2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Option 2** was perfect. In the end I used the `@Component.host approach.