# Can I do two things at once in a structural directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'd like to create a structural directive which behaves as follows:

```
<p *myDirective="condition">This is some text</p>
```

- If `condition` is `false` then the `<p>` tag is **not** rendered at all.
- If `condition` is `true` then the `<p>` tag is rendered with an extra `class` attribute.

So, either there's *nothing* rendered, or:

```
<p class="my-added-class">This is some text</p>
```

In other words, it's a bit like `*ngIf`, but with additional behaviour.

I can find examples of how to do the include/exclude behaviour (in fact there is such an example [in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive)). I can also find examples of how to add a class to an element [using the `Renderer2` API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820610/98422).

However, I don't see how I can combine these techniques, because the first method manipulates the `viewContainer` to create an embedded *view*, whereas the second method uses the renderer to manipulate an *element*.

**Is there a way to do this?** Can I somehow create the embedded view and then manipulate the elements it creates? Or can I manipulate the template to change how the view is rendered?

[NOTE: `@HostBinding` does not work with structural directives, so that's not an option]

Comment: Why don't you want to just use `*ngIf` along with `ngClass` and do the needful based on a condition? Something like `<p *ngIf="condition" [class.yourClass]="condition">This is some text</p>`

Comment: When you create the embedded view, you can grab the rendered elements with the rootNodes property: `const viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef); viewRef.rootNodes[0].classList.add('my-added-class');` Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mdlht

Comment: @SiddAjmera: Errrm… because I want to wrap those two things together in a directive? So that every time I use it, I just need to type a single directive, and it does everything for me. I mean, I *could* just type everything out, but… I *could* just use HTML :-)

Comment: @AlexK: that looks perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other way

just to play around :)

Using Renderer2 is universal safe

```
import {
  Directive,
  Renderer2,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ElementRef,
  Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMy]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit{
  constructor(
  private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
  private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
  private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  @Input() set appMy(condition: boolean) {
   if (condition) {
     this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else  {
     this.viewContainer.clear();
   }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const elementRef = this.viewContainer.get(0).rootNodes[0] as ElementRef;
    this.renderer.addClass(elementRef, 'myclass');
  }
}
```

Following the @Pankaj way but with renderer

```
@Input() set appMy(condition: boolean) {
   if (condition) {
     const view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
     this.renderer.addClass(view.rootNodes[0], 'myclass');
   } else  {
     this.viewContainer.clear();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with your second suggestion, because it puts everything in one place, and because it doesn't involve injecting the ElementRef etc. One thing to note is that it works for `<p *myDirective="condition">text</p>` but **not** for `<ng-template myCondition="condition">text</ng-template>` because in the latter case there's no element to add a class to. (I can live with that).

Answer (score 3):

I'd think of adding class on the DOM when it satisfied the expression passed to it (inside setter). You can grab the `ElementRef` dependency inside directive and append a `class` to it which its truthy.

```
@Input() set myDirective(condition: boolean) {
  if (condition) {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add('my-added-class'); // renderer API can be used here
    // as Alex and Yurzui suggested
    // const view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef); 
    // view.rootNodes[0].classList.add('some-class')
  } else if (condition) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that. But it gives an error saying `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

Comment: Don't forget that for structural directive elementRef refers to the comment node

Comment: Another way is `const view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      view.rootNodes[0].classList.add('some-class')` but we should know exactly that template contains element on top level