# How to add and modify element in an angular TemplateRef

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created a simple Angular directive where I control whether an element will be shown or not. What I am unable to perform is the following:

1. Modify an attribute of the element where this directive is used
2. Add an html element to the same element

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[needPermission]'
})
export class NeedPermissionDirective {
  private visible = true;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef < any > , private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

  @Input() set needPermission(permissionId: string) {
    if (this.visible === true) {
      // TODO-1: Modify an attribute for an element within the templateRef
      // TODO-2: Add an html element to the templateRef like a <div>        
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }

  })
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325398/can-i-do-two-things-at-once-in-a-structural-directive

Answer (score 0):

here's an example to modify  attributes

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[imgError]'
})
export class ImgErrorDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    try{
      this._elRef.nativeElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
        .childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes
        .forEach((child: any)=>{
           this._renderer.setAttribute(child.childNodes[0]
             .childNodes[0].childNodes[0], 'onerror', "this.src='assets/img/no- 
               photo.jpg'");
      });
    }catch{}
  }
}
```

In this example, I am looping a childNodes list containing img and modifying the onerror attribute of each.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work as "this._elRef.nativeElement" is a comment node (created from ng-template) and has no children nodes

Comment: Have you verified your *ngIf condition?

Comment: yes I have verified and seems correct

Comment: You can use [hidden] instead of *ngIf, it won't comment the code. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element.