# Add a class to directive in angular

Tags: angular, class

I have a simple directive and I would like to add a class to it :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFieldLabel]',
})
export class FieldLabelDirective {
  @Input() tooltip: string;
  @Input() showOptional = true;

  @HostBinding('class.text-truncate')
  test = true;
}
```

this works, but I want it to always be set, is there a way without assigning an useless property like here `test = true;`

thank you

Comment: there are more options to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639098/using-a-directive-to-add-class-to-host-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `prop = true` you can just bind to `class` and then set value to a classes that you want, like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFieldLabel]',
})
export class FieldLabelDirective {
  @Input() tooltip: string;
  @Input() showOptional = true;

  @HostBinding('class') private hostClass = 'text-truncate';
}
```

It's less useless, because you can modify classes via variable.

You could also bind class like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFieldLabel]',
  host: {
    'class': 'text-truncate',
  }
})
export class FieldLabelDirective {
  // the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: the second option tell me is deprecated, I will do the first I guess

Comment: Which version of angular do you use?

Comment: I use 12. Anyway, I went with your first solution.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I checked the official docs and there's no word about deprecation. I also checked on my machine and eslint isn't complaining. I guess it may be related to your eslint/tslint config.