# Angular2: Directive variable change, update element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, directive

I'm currently trying to give classes to an wrapper that contains all of my app, i usually find this handy for giving certain states like when the header is fixed, or the menu's are opened etc.

So upon reading through some the docs of angular i should probably use an 'Directive'. Now i got this all set up and it looks like this:

```
constructor(private router:Router, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document:Document, el:ElementRef, renderer:Renderer) {
    this.setClasses(el, renderer);
}

setClasses(el:ElementRef, renderer:Renderer) {
    renderer.setElementClass(el.nativeElement, 'header-fixed', this.headerFixed);
}

@HostListener("window:scroll", [])onWindowScroll() {
    let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;

    if (number > 100) {
        this.headerFixed = true;
    } else if (this.headerFixed && number < 10) {
        this.headerFixed = false;
    }
}
```

Now this is working perfectly but as you can see i'm toggling the `headerFixed` variable depending on scroll position. However i could of course run the function `setClasses()` again and it will work but is there anyway to subscribe/watch the variable and update automatically when changed?

Or is there even a better way of achieving wat i'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried to use `@HostBinding('header-fixed')` together with getter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168683/hostbinding-with-a-variable-class-in-angular2

Comment: Ah yeah that works thanks!

Comment: 1 more thing, it's sort of related, for example within the directive selector i have an button that toggles menuOpen like: `(click)="menuOpen = !menuOpen"` in the directive the variable is declared like: `@HostBinding('class.menu-open') menuOpen = false;` but it doesn't work. Any idea hoe to best handle those kind of events?

Comment: What about using getter?

Comment: Could you post an example link? Would be appreciated, also if you post an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Can you show me example of html with `click` event?

Comment: `<div class="menu-toggle" (click)="menuOpen = !menuOpen">
            <span></span>
        </div>` it's within the directive's selector but has it's in another component. (header.component)

Comment: Does your directive has input property [menuOpen]="menuOpen"?

Comment: wrapper-class.directive.ts has `@HostBinding('class.menu-open') menuOpen = false;` 

header.component.ts is empty only assigning the template and styles in here.

Comment: Take this as example https://plnkr.co/edit/GL0Qdb4N9z3Z8Itaq0Ta?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the example, seems to do everything i want, only for some reason i get an type error when i try to to compile this locally. `wrapper-class.directive.ts:12:44 
    '(' expected.
` it's becasue of the `get redClass { ... }`

Comment: i think the example you gave me is not working because my structure is a bit different, my app.component is loading header.component and within the header.component template the button is located. Doesn't mater if i define `menuOpen` there, i'm still getting some errors.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on the plunker?

Comment: Of course:  https://plnkr.co/edit/leWupEhc0MsSrX0VjcvF?p=preview

Comment: I don't see where you use `MyDirective`

Comment: My badd updated it, it wraps the header https://plnkr.co/edit/48sxN2WIjuhRcoZN5T3S?p=preview

Comment: See my plunker within answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@HostBinding` like:

```
@HostBinding('class.header-fixed') get myClass() { 
  return someCondition; 
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ujlA8ASKJb8yQQgjO7gp?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks! Will check tomorrow morning of i can get it to work.